# GIS: use .tif on data layer for Google Map

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, gis

i have three files that i should use for a GIS application:
map.aux, map.tfw, map.tif

The .tif file is a "layer" that highlights some building over a map. These files are georeferenced to specific coordinates.

How can i bring these informations (and "image") on a layer of Google Maps? Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think Google Map has some api to load .tif file as a layer!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you code since I've never tested, but the following should work:

You can use the ground overlay object coming from Gmaps:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay

It allows you specify an image in format of "BitmapDescriptor" and eventually anchor and bearing of the given tif.

The good for you is that, if you've already georefenced the file and it is in the default Google Maps projection (900913 or 3857, Mercator) you don't need to rotate data. Just take out the position of the raster from aux/tfw files (there should be a line specifying the topleft coordinate for the raster and the size of it; from those lines you should be able with some math to get the LatLng bounds needed to initialize the groundOverlay.

The only part I'm not sure is easy is to create a BitmapDescriptor from a tiff. If this is not easy or impossible, just reconvert the tif to png, that will possible to read and put in a BitmapDescriptor.

Maybe is not the code for you question, but at least a starting point!

Answer (score 0):

With R you can do

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('map.tif')
KML(r, 'map.kml')
```

open the .kml file in Google earth.

See package `plotKML` for more advanced options